# Calculation over multiple rows and assign to one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want update the table to sum up some rows (not all row) and update a row named "Total".

Then base on the Total, I will do some calculation with some other rows and set result into row called Sub.

Table I have is something like

```
        id  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
R1      1   1  12  2  3  5
R2      2   3  3  41  4  3
R3      3   5  3  32  2  6
Total   4   = R1 + R2 + R3
R4      5   1  2  4  13  4 
R5      6   3  5  1   3  4
Sub     7   = Total - R4 - R5
```

Based on the calculation above I'm supposed to get a table like this

```
      id   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 
R1    1    1  12  2  3  5
R2    2    3  3  41  4  3
R3    3    5  3  32  2  6
Total 4    9  18 75  9  14
R4    5    1  2  4  13  4 
R5    6    3  5  1   3  4
Sub   7    5  11 70 -7  6
```

Also this is a temp table.

I tried rollup but doesn't seem to perform this job.

```
update #tempreport
set C1 = sum(C1),
    C2 = sum(C2),
    C3 = sum(C3), 
    C4 = sum(C4), 
    C5 = sum(C5)
where id = 4 and id between 1 and 3
```

but I got an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I'm really stuck, and I feel like the second requirement is even more challenging and I have no clue how to perform something like that in SQL. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know which rows you are supposed to add / subtract?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis it's pretty much fixed so don't need to be dynamic. Thank you for the answer,that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Step 1: update the "SUM" row (in the example it has id = 4)
update #tempreport set C1 = sum1, C2 = sum2, C3 = sum3, C4 = sum4, C5 = sum5
from (
    select sum(C1) as sum1, sum(C2) as sum2, sum(C3) as sum3, 
           sum(C4) as sum4, sum(C5) as sum5
    from #tempreport
    where id between 1 and 3
) sums
where #tempreport.id = 4
;

-- Step 2: update the "DIFF" row (id = 7):
update #tempreport set #tempreport.C1 = x.C1-sum1, #tempreport.C2 = x.C2-sum2,    
                       #tempreport.C3 = x.C3-sum3, #tempreport.C4 = x.C4-sum4, 
                       #tempreport.C5 = x.C5-sum5
from (
    select sum(C1) as sum1, sum(C2) as sum2, sum(C3) as sum3, 
           sum(C4) as sum4, sum(C5) as sum5
    from #tempreport
    where id between 5 and 6
) subtr, (select * from #tempreport where id = 4) x
where #tempreport.id = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer for the first part of the question. 
credit to this [link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-157.aspx)

use a subquery. In this case I would

```
update #tempreport
set C1 = tbl.C1, 
    C2 = tbl.C2, 
    C3 = tbl.C3, 
    C4 = tbl.C4,
    C5 = tbl.C5
from (
     select id, sum(C1) as C1, sum(C2) as C2, sum(C3) as C3...
     from #tempreport
     where id between 1 and 3
) as tbl
where id=4
```